# Add an profile image next to an post corresponding to the user in Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I was trying to make that when there was a post made by user `John whit` `user_id` 1
It check if he has an profile and if he has an profile it puts the image next to it that corresponds to the user and the profile he or she created. so when I login whit the user it works fine because I'm getting the user id out of

```
   Auth::user()->id
```

But when I log in whit another user and look at the page I get off an error.

**Error:**

> Trying to get property 'id' of non-object (View: 
>      C:\Users\Merlijn\AppData\Roaming\Composer\Laravel 
>      Projects\blog\resources\views\posts\post.blade.php) (View: 
>      C:\Users\Merlijn\AppData\Roaming\Composer\Laravel 
>      Projects\blog\resources\views\posts\post.blade.php)

so mine question is How can I make that the Image that belongs to the user is connected to the post the user image and post are in 3 different tables.
here how I try to do it now?

**Post.blade.php**

```
<div class="blog-post">

  <h2 class="blog-post-title">

    <a href="{{ route('posts.show', ["post" => $post->id]) }}">

     {{ $post->title }}

    </a>

</h2>

<p class="blog-post-meta">

    @foreach($image as $path)
        @if(Auth::user()->id == $path->user_id)
        {{--{{dd($path)}}--}}
            @if(!$path->image_path == null)
                <img src="/images/{{ $path->image_path }}" id="imgProfile" style="width: 150px; height: 150px" class="img-thumbnail" />
            @else
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"   id="imgProfile" style="width: 150px; height: 150px" class="img-thumbnail" />
            @endif
        @endif
    @endforeach

    <a href="#">{{ $post->user->name }}</a> on

    {{ $post->created_at->toFormattedDateString() }}

</p>

<p>
    {{
    $post->body
    }}
</p>

<br>

@if (Auth::check())

    @if(Auth::user()->id == $post->user_id)
    <div class="button-box col-lg-12">

        <a href="{{ route('posts.edit', ["post" => $post->id]) }}" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Edit</a>
        <a href="{{ route('posts.delete', ["post" => $post->id]) }}" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Delete</a>

    </div>

    @endif

@endif

<hr>
```

**AppService provider**

```
<?php

  namespace App\Providers;

 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
 use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
 use View;
 use App\Profile;

 class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);

    view()->composer('layouts.sidebar', function($view){

        $view->with('archives', \App\Post::archives());

    });

    View::share('image', Profile::all());
}

/**
 * Register any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    //
}
 }
```

If u need anything like extra information note it and I will edit it in

Comment: You should use` Auth::check()` to verify if user is logged in  in and then do `Auth::user()->id` etc

Comment: Which version of laravel you are using?

Comment: If laravel version is old you have to wrap your routes inside web middleware to get auth user information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as Suborno said, you shouldn't use `Auth::user()->id` since this will always put the image of the logged in user there.
You want to link a user to the post with a one to many relationship and then you can use `$post->user->id`
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

```
class post extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

```
@foreach($image as $path)
        @if($post->user->id == $path->user_id)
        {{--{{dd($path)}}--}}
            @if(!$path->image_path == null)
                <img src="/images/{{ $path->image_path }}" id="imgProfile" style="width: 150px; height: 150px" class="img-thumbnail" />
            @else
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"   id="imgProfile" style="width: 150px; height: 150px" class="img-thumbnail" />
            @endif
        @endif
    @endforeach
```

note: this all depends on how you have your models/database set up.

Answer (score 0):

How are you expecting **Auth::user()->id** to work if you are not logged in?

Auth::user() only has the session data of the logged in user.

Change this condition **@if(Auth::user()->id == $path->user_id)** to something more suitable like (!empty) if you are willing to access multiple users data or without logging in at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
@foreach($image as $path)
        @if(Auth::user()->id == $path->user_id)
            @if(!$path->image_path == null)
                <img src="/images/{{ $path->image_path }}" id="imgProfile" style="width: 150px; height: 150px" class="img-thumbnail" />
            @else
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"   id="imgProfile" style="width: 150px; height: 150px" class="img-thumbnail" />
            @endif
        @else
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"   id="imgProfile" style="width: 150px; height: 150px" class="img-thumbnail" />
        @endif
    @endforeach
```

Hope this helps :)